# Reading a configuration section from a stream - possible?

Tags: .net, configuration, stream

I have the following problem:

I need to get a ConfigurationSection - object from a stream that contains a well formed app.config - file (which will  has to be loaded from the assembly resource streams).

Is there any way to load that from a stream?

Background (to satisfy the "why would you want that" questions):

I'm working on some kind of plugin - system based on Unity (and no - I CAN NOT use MEF, because MEF doesn't support Unity and it's all a pain).

My idea is to have a "extension manifest" - file as a resource in the plugin - assemblies which have the same format as an app.config file but are only there to setup the Unity - IoC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is pretty old, but will surely helps:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060622.asp

Comment: Answer with just a link is not very useful.